# Sorting VARCHAR column with alphanumeric entries (start with numerics)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
1
1one
2
2two
11
11eleven
11
22twentytwo
111oneeleven
552
3311
A1
A10
A11
A100
AB1
AB10
AB10A
AB100
AB100
B1
B2
B3
B3
B20
B20BB
B21BC
B21
B32
```

i want above list in below sort order.

```
1
2
11
11
552
3311
1one
2two
11eleven
22twentytwo
111oneeleven
A1
A10
A11
A100
AB1
AB10
AB10A
AB100
AB100
B1
B2
B3
B3
B20
B20BB
B21BC
B21
B32
```

The query is:

```
SELECT 
    Section,
    LEFT(Section, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Section) - 1) AS left1,
    PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Section) startindex,
    LEN(Section) AS length,
    PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(Section)) AS revindex,
    LEN(Section) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(Section)) + 1 positionofendint,
    SUBSTRING(Section, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Section), LEN(Section) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(Section)) + 1) integerpart,
    LEN(Section) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(Section)) + 1 - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Section) + 1 subintlength,
    ISNUMERIC(section) isnumeric1,
    LEFT(Section, PATINDEX('[0-9]', Section)) onlyint
FROM 
    dbo.Section
WHERE 
    section NOT IN ('33A100', '55B32', '55B1', '55AB100', '99AB10A', '99B21BC', '1B20BB', '6B2B', '3AB1', '4a1', '7A11', '99B3')
    --where  section not like '%B%' and section not like '%A%' and section not like '%o%' and section not like '%e%' 
--ORDER BY section
--, CONVERT(INT,(case when isnumeric(section)=1 then section end))
ORDER BY  
    LEFT(Section, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Section) - 1), -- alphabetical sort
    CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(Section, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Section),
    LEN(Section) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(Section)) + 1 - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Section) + 1)) -- numerical sort
```

Here, Word started with Alphabets are sorting and next to that numbers are also sorting but word started with numbers are not sorted, please help me on how to sort the word started numbers with characters.

Comment: You cannot have both MYSQL and SQL-SERVER, please remove the tag of the RDMS which you aren't using

Comment: The order you are stating you want is extremely difficult because you are mixing datatypes in your sort. You want to sort all only numeric values first and those need to be sorted like numbers, not character data, then you want the values that contain character data to sort the same way. You really can't do this.

Comment: @SeanLange I believe I've figured out a solution but you're more than welcome to tell me where I went horribly wrong :) **EDIT:** Realized it myself. I'm close but my alpha-numeric sort will mix-up on values like `AB10A` being *before* `AB100`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a simple case statement? This doesn't match your results specifically, but it correctly sorts the varchar part, after the (what could be) and integer part.

```
declare @table table (v varchar(64))
insert into @table
values
('1'),
('1one'),
('2'),
('2two'),
('11'),
('11eleven'),
('11'),
('22twentytwo'),
('111oneeleven'),
('552'),
('3311'),
('A1'),
('A10'),
('A11'),
('A100'),
('AB1'),
('AB10'),
('AB10A'),
('AB100'),
('AB100'),
('B1'),
('B2'),
('B3'),
('B3'),
('B20'),
('B20BB'),
('B21BC'),
('B21'),
('B32')

select v
from @table
order by case when v like '%[^0-9]%' then v end, v
```

Comment: This is pretty good but realistically the OP wants to sort this data in a way that is really difficult. Notice how the character data is sorted by numbers and then characters?

Comment: I agree @SeanLange, and it almost seems like you'd have to sort on the length some how first too? Odd i agree, but it'll get them started.

Comment: I think you would have to first those values that are only numbers to the top and sort them by numeric value. Then the remainder would have to find leading numbers and sort those by the leading numeric values. Finally add the last data which is just sorted by the characters. What a nightmarish mess.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `CASE` that you're after is something like this:

```
SELECT Section
FROM dbo.Section
ORDER BY
    --Primary sort puts results that start with a letter to the end
    --Otherwise, sorts by where the occurrence of the first letter is
    CASE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', Section) WHEN 1 then 99 ELSE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', Section) END, 

    --Secondary sort will sort numeric values by length instead of number
    CASE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', Section) WHEN 1 then 99 ELSE LEN(Section) END, 

    --Final sort alpha-numeric
    Section
```

*(Thank you to scsimon, who's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45356187/2026606) scripted out the table creation required to test this.)*

**EDIT:** The query above will get you close, however the alpha-numeric sort has issues. It will return `AB100` before `AB10A` (etc), will take a deeper look.

Comment: This is close but still not quite there. The second round of sorting needs to sort by the leading number of the character data. To see this work incorrectly change '2two' to '2to'. This kind of sorting is just awful.

Comment: Yeah I've just realized, thank you. Kinda burnt myself out on this for the time being but plan to come back to the drawing board later.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it almost close, only AB100 coming first

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestData;

SELECT 
    x.SomeValue
    INTO #TestData
FROM
    ( VALUES 
        ('1'), ('1one'), ('2'), ('2two'), ('11'), ('11eleven'), ('11'), ('22twentytwo'), ('111oneeleven'),
        ('552'), ('3311'), ('A1'), ('A10'), ('A11'), ('A100'), ('AB1'), ('AB10'), ('AB10A'), ('AB100'),
        ('AB100'), ('B1'), ('B2'), ('B3'), ('B3'), ('B20'), ('B20BB'), ('B21BC'), ('B21'), ('B32')
    ) x (SomeValue);

SELECT 
    td.SomeValue
FROM
    #TestData td

ORDER BY 

    CASE WHEN td.SomeValue NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN CAST(td.SomeValue AS INT) ELSE 2147483647 END,
    CASE WHEN LEFT(td.SomeValue, 1) BETWEEN '0' AND '9' AND td.SomeValue LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(td.SomeValue, 1, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', td.SomeValue) - 1) AS INT) ELSE 2147483647 END,      
    td.SomeValue;
```

HTH, Jason